# Django Form With ManyToMany Using TextInput instead of MultiSelect

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

Using the following i can get a multi select area, but what i would like is to have users be able to add authors using `<input type="text">` for author name and a drop down for title. The way it is written we would have to know all the possible authors for books which is not plausible. Ideally there would be + so someone could add multiple authors to the same book.

I am using form based views, you can see the code as of the writing of this question [here](https://github.com/Victory/fun-with-forms/tree/5c24a96c5989377e27da7ea7054ce21e485074a1)

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

TITLE_CHOICES = (('MR', 'Mr.'),('MRS', 'Mrs.'),('MS', 'Ms.'))


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20})
        }


class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, request, commit=True):
        super(BookForm, self).save(request)
        pass
```

The html might be something like this (with different `name` attributes)

```
<input type="text" name="booktitle">
<div>
  <select><option>Mr</option><option>Mrs</option></select>
  <input type="text" name="authorName">
  <button name="clickOneToAddAnotherAuthor">
</div>
<div>
  <select><option>Mr</option><option>Mrs</option></select>
  <input type="text" name="authorName">
  <button name="clickOneToAddAnotherAuthor">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.ChoiceField()
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
            'title': forms.Select(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20})
        }
```

Comment: unfortunately the "name" field is still a `<select>` box not a list of text inputs.

Comment: What do you mean by list of text inputs? Can you give an html example?